# knowledge:articleRendererToolbar - edit link is not working

Tags: knowledge, articles

```
 <knowledge:articleRendererToolbar articleId="{!knowledgeId}" showChatter="true"
  rendered="true" canVote="false" />
```

Using knowledge:articleRendererToolbar edit link is not working and it is redirecting to the same page with view only access, page should be open in edit mode but it is not working in edit

Answer (score 0):

I tried but couldn't reproduce that edit does not work in my org. I am using the below VF code

```
<apex:page standardController="Knowledge__kav" showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
<knowledge:articleRendererToolBar articleId="{!Knowledge__kav.knowledgeArticleId}" showChatter="false" canVote="false" />
</apex:page>
```

I am passing an Id of Knowledge article in URL which has PublishStatus as 'Online'

```
https://testsummer19org-dev-ed--c.visualforce.com/apex/KBTEST?id=kA0B0000000J864#
```

I am being redirected to the below screen which permits me to edit the article
[image]
If you try these same steps, are you still not able to edit?

Comment: @cloudZigZag Have you had a chance to check my inputs. Happy to answer any follow-up queries.Thanks